# How to retry failed webservice calls?

Tags: web-services

We have a .net WCF webservice hosted on a windows service host.

On some specific calls from the client, this WCF webservice should invoke a third party webservice(which is not a WCF service). (B2B call)
Now the problem is that the third party service may not be up always. We may have to retry the failed calls for few more times on specified intervels. What is the best approach to do this?

We have ruled out msmq. What all are the other options? can I use a simple timer with in our windows service host and make periodic call to this external service? or should I use windows task scheduler? Please help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Try DotNetMQ. It's not just MSMQ equivalent but a lot better way of queueing calls and retrying. It guarantees reliable delivery of messages.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/DotNetMQ.aspx

Let me know if this works or not. if not, then we will discuss alternatives.